# DotnetBrowser and Mono for ARM

Tags: dotnetbrowser

Anyone know if there is a way to get https://www.teamdev.com/dotnetbrowser to work with Mono for ARM?

We have an ARM device and we would love to have it to work in it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the current version of DotNetBrowser does not support the Mono platform.

Comment: Thanks! Sad to head that :(